# Folding, accumulate, for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, functional-programming, fold, c++20

Everywhere I read that you must use std algorithms everywhere you can.

Here is the problem I wanted to solve.
I have a big vector of bytes that I want to separate into chunks.

So, I began something without algorithms, and it was a bit complicates, so I tried to decompose things.

Here is the "chunk manager"

```
struct ChunkManager {
public:
    void push_byte(std::byte byte) noexcept {m_bytes[index++] = byte;}
    bool isComplete() const noexcept {return m_index == 256;}
    auto getChunk() const noexcept {return m_bytes;}
private:
    std::size_t index{0};
    std::array<std::byte, 256> m_bytes;
};
```

Once we are here, it is easier.
We have to perform a left fold (std accumulate with C++20 improvements (move semantics)) with the following lambda.

```
auto gatherChunks = [](auto chunks, auto byte) {
    if(chunks.back().isComplete()) {
        chunks.emplace_back(ChunkManager{});
    }
    chunks.back().push_byte(byte);
    return chunks;
};
```

We perform the accumulation:

```
auto bytes = std::vector<std::byte>{...};
auto chunks = std::accumulate(begin(bytes), end(bytes),
              std::vector{ChunkManager{}}, 
              gatherChunks);
```

The lambda is a bit complicate...
A for range loop could do the job better:

```
auto bytes = std::vector<std::byte>{...};
auto chunks = std::vector{ChunkManager{}};
for(auto byte: bytes) {
    if(chunks.back().isComplete()) {
        chunks.emplace_back(ChunkManager{});
    }
    chunks.back().push_byte(byte);
}
```

In this case, it seems the for loop is easier to understand than the accumulate one. Do I miss something? Is there a better way to separate a big buffer into chunks?

Comment: There's no rule that says you must *always* do something. *Often* using standard algorithms leads to more readable code, but sometimes it does not. Use whatever makes the most sense in any given situation.

Comment: The only advantage in my mind to `std::accumulate` is that if you are just going to pass `chunks` to another function, you can do it without the temporary `chunks` variable. All else being equal, the code that is easier to read is the better code.

Comment: As far as a better way to produce the chunks there a number of optimizations available. First, making copies should be avoided if possible, so if you can ensure that the source data will out live the chunks, you could just store pointers into the original buffer. If not, calculating how much of the source is left and copying into the chunk in bulk instead of one byte at a time will be much faster. In either case, calculating how many chunks are needed up front will allow you to reserve the space for the vector of chunks instead of letting it grow it as needed.

Comment: @nate Thanks, I was more interested in code readability than performance, but yes, you are right :)

Comment: You left a lot of blanks for me to fill in, so I don't know who messed up, or if my compiler just isn't updated, but I get errors. The parameters to accumulate don't seem to match the docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: @AntoineMorrier yea I guess it depends on what metric you are using for better ;)

Comment: @KennyOstrom It should be ok normally. Two iterators, an initial values, and a callback wxith 2 arguments. I just fix the lambdas because I forget the return value :)

Comment: Is the question specifically about chunking into 256-byte ranges, or is that just an example and the real question is about this kind of arbitrary completion predicate?

Comment: @Barry It was just an example. It can be chunk of different size in reality :-)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier That... doesn't answer my question. Is the question is about chunking a range by an arbitrary size `N`? The title is "Folding, accumulate, for loop" - is the question actually "How can I chunk a range into smaller ranges of size N?" or is chunking just an example of any arbtirary predicate?

Comment: @Barry. Chunking is just an example. The true question is more "Is using std accumulate better in all circonstances even if it means the code feels less natural :-)"

Comment: In your case I don't see an algorithm that would make the intent much clearer than a hand-written loop. But that doesn't mean that there is no such algorithm. Yet I would not use the range for loop, I would build a `span` over the complete `vector` and while it has more than 256 elements I would build a `ChunkManager` from a sub range of the first 256 elements and then remove that sub range from the complete range. A better solution might be the ranges library, but I have not yet checked what it provides.